# Show requests data from EC2 using Cloudwatch Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, slack

I have developed a small chatbot which is integrated in the slack workspace. The app itself is deployed on EC2 machine and runs there (obviously, in API manner). So every time when somebody interacted with the bot in slack, the query is being printed out in the EC2. My question is the following - how am I able to see these queries from the users in Cloudwatch?

I have set up the IAM role for the EC2 and gave `CloudWatchFullAccess` permission also I know how to send the simple machine logs to Cloudwatch (by using `awslogs` library) but I am not able to save the queries information by using this approach. What am I doing wrong here and how this task can be done?

Thanks in advance.